# How do I keep my Android app continuously connected with my own RESTful API to retrieve data continuously?

Tags: android, rest, real-time

Please help me guys ! Please

I am using *retrofit* to connect with my RESTful API which is running on Express and Node. Now I want to fetch my data from api continuously means there should be a continuous connection of my app with api.

Retrofit enqueues the requests and we need to keep it sending again and again. I've tried by creating a retrofit call inside a services but it reflects the UI constantly which means it makes call continuously.

So how can I do that? DO I need to make my restful service a real-time? or is there any way to make this calls? (Please don't tell me about Firebase or Parse or Anything)

Comment: You can create a thread that calls api and which runs every X interval. But I feed it will be better to use sockets

Comment: Can we bound UI with sockets ? and will that keep my connections without refreshing or enquing the requests? @PriyeshKumar

Comment: One advice to you. Whatever u ll follow just restrict your app from using background data otherwise android ll flag your app to battery drainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a lot about your requirements, but if you really need to keep up a connection to your backend continuously, then maybe REST is not a good way to achieve that.

If you do not want to result to some proprietary solutions like you mentioned, there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want to, using Socket Connections with a data format like `protobuf` and a methodology like `RPC` to communicate.
I have not used it before but after brief googling I found http://www.grpc.io/ which sounds rather promising.

If you want to keep up REST as your API type, then you will need to resort to a poll based approach or maybe a Push (notification) based approach, where you just constantly poll your endpoint, or start polling for new data after a push notification is received.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments... In your case you could have a look at https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/ to connect live data from your backend to an app. It will work just fine if your backend can handle the requirements that come with keeping up a lot of connections with your clients.

Comment: I saw the grpc.io but it's again an RPC framework and the REST is always preferred over RPC i guess . And as you said the push-poll implementation the continuous polling is what I want to avoid. Because there is a constant pushing notification and making calls to api in my requirements. So How can I ?

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure if I understand what you mean correctly. A REST endpoint is by definition based on Http Request/ Responses through methods like GET, POST, PUT etc. So In order to get a response, you first need to make a request. If you want to maintain your data in a bidirectional manner, you will need to stream it somehow, which will require some sort of persistant connection. RPC is just a way of doing that. OKHttp can do websockets, as far as I know. Maybe that will help? https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988

Comment: If i say that I will make my RESTful database a realtime db then will that web-socket keep the app synced with my API?

Comment: A realtime database is just a term used these days for tools, that synchronise data over socket connections, so it's the same everywhere you look at it. It's really easy to use those things. If you are planning on connecting A LOT of devices to your service, than it's definitely recommended to use any of the realtime databases available, since well... keeping up connections with a lot of phones is a lot of work! If you plan to keep it simple and small you could follow the following tutorial for server/ client with sockets: https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: Wow.. I have seen the socket.io before but I didn't know how to exactly connect android client with socket. Thanks a lott for mentioning it ! I request you to edit your answer and add the above comment in it I will mark it solved! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by initiating your API call inside a Handler, which will run in a time interval. It will call your API every time when the Handler runs.
You can do it like this:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Initiate your API here
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

It will intiate your API in every 5 seconds(5000 miliseconds).

Comment: Android will flag application to battery drainer in some phones like OnePlus series. So this is the worst solution

Comment: @BabulPatel is right and continuous polling (making calls to API) is not a good practice I guess because I tried this in some different way using Services in android and I initiated the api in Services onCreate().